# Arquitetura Funcionario -> Meta

Tags: java, java-ee, arquitetura-de-software

A dúvida que eu tenho é totalmente arquitetural. Vou expor um caso logo abaixo para ilustrar melhor a duvida na qual eu estou batendo direto em meu sistema.

Tenho uma funcionalidade que tem como objetivo cadastrar um funcionário. Tal funcionário é composto por campos básicos como nome, sobrenome, data de nascimento, função e etc... OK! Até aí não temos problema algum, mas esse funcionário tem associado com ele as metas de venda que precisa cumprir, ou seja, em cada mês do ano tenho um valor "atrelado".

Se formos imaginar o relacionamento entre tais entidades, logo eu criei algo assim:

Um funcionário tem muitas metas, que por sua vez tem os meses do ano.

Abaixo estão os `bean's` de forma reduzida:

```
public class Funcionario implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;

        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
        @JoinColumn(name = "fk_metas")
        private Meta metas;

        ///Getters and Setters
}

public class Meta implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String ano;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "metas")
    private Set<Mes> meses;

    ///Getters and Setters
}

public class Mes implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_ano")
    private Meta metas;

    private Double janeiro;

    private Double fevereiro;

    ///Getters and Setters... Meses restantes
    }
```

Seria essa forma a mais inteligente?

Comment: Por que não faz assim: `Funcionario { List<Meta> metas; }` e `Meta { double valor; Date mesReferência; }`? Já que o mês pertence a um ano em particular, é normal armazená-lo em um tipo *date* setando o dia sempre como dia primeiro. Se você não gosta, ainda tem a opção de fazer assim: `Meta { double valor; int mesReferência; int anoReferência; }`, embora eu prefira a primeira opção porque vai simplificar muita coisa: a apresentação da data, a listagem por período e o cálculo entre datas, por exemplo.

Comment: Então @Caffé na verdade os meses vão ter que ser fixos, pois cada mês corresponde a um input onde o usuário irá colocar qual a meta (valor em reais), terá que ser atingido naquele mês.

Comment: E o meu modelo não serve? Pelo que vejo, serve.

Comment: Então devo ter interpretado de forma errada. Peço desculpas, mas não entendi. Irei analisar sua proposta melhor. Obrigado

Comment: Veja se o teu modelo cobre alguma coisa que o meu não cobre, e fique a vontade para perguntar.